# Can I enable directory listing in the Snowpack dev server?

Tags: webpack, snowpack

I'm looking into using [Snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/) as an alternative to [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). By default, if I run the webpack dev server (`webpack serve`) and no default document exists, browsing to `http://localhost:8080` gives me a directory listing. I want to enable the same behaviour in Snowpack, but by default it's returning a 404 Not Found when I browse to `/`. Is there a config setting or a plugin I can use to enable directory browsing so it works in a similar way to Webpack?

[image: screenshots of http://localhost:8080/ served by webpack serve and by snowpack dev]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default snowpack doesn't provide that kind of functionality out of the box. But that doesn't mean it's impossible.

You could use [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) with [snowpack server](https://www.snowpack.dev/guides/server-side-render#option-2%3A-on-demand-serving-(middleware)) and fallback to [serve-index](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-index#serve-directory-indexes-with-express) if nothing is found.

Basically you'll have to implement it yourself. But it's not that difficult

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news bud, but I dont think such a thing is able to be done on snowpack.
The two bundlers operate a slightly different server, Snowpack needs to use the index.html to route the server to, webpack opens a server the port first then goes off and hosts the files. ( a slightly simplistic take on the two)
Sorry I wish I could of been more helpful man,